# Can I directly record a Jibri meeting to S3 without saving in EC2 instance in AWS

Tags: amazon-s3, recording, jitsi

I am using 2 server Jitsi meet and Jibri server for recording I am able to record a meet in local directory of Jibri server can I able  to record directly to S3 bucket can I get a script for saving my meet directly to S3 , I can able to copy and delete from the server to S3
This will copy and delete I need to store directly to S3 without storing in EC2

```
#!/bin/bash
# Set your AWS credentials`s3`
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=`My_ACCESS_KEY_ID`
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=`My_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`
export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION="Region"

# Set the source folder and S3 bucket name
SOURCE_FOLDER="/Myrecordingfolder"
S3_BUCKET_NAME="mybucket"

# Upload the folder to S3
aws s3 sync "${SOURCE_FOLDER}" "s3://${S3_BUCKET_NAME}"

# Delete the files and directories inside the recording directory
#find "${SOURCE_FOLDER}" -mindepth 1 -de
```

And can I display the meeting video stored in S3 and display them in a website